# ionic cordova download generated csv to specific path/directory in android via filetransfer plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I am using "Papa Parse" in my ionic project to generate a csv-file.

```
let csv = papa.unparse({
        fields: this.headerRow,
        data: this.csvData
    }, { delimiter: ";" });

    var blob = new Blob([csv]);

    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = moment().format('LLL') + ".csv";

    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    this.showToast("File was downloaded");
```

On my PC/Mac it will downloaded in my "download"-folder by default. On the device it there is no error, but I checked all the folders and I cannot find the file. Appearently, to make it work on mobile device I had to include the File-Transfer-plugin from cordova....

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

      if(this.platform.is('android')) {

        console.log(cordova.file.applicationDirectory);

        var blob = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = moment().format('LLL') + ".csv";

        console.log(a.href);
        console.log(a.download);


        const csvLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www/${blob}`;

        fileTransfer.download(a.href, this.storageDirectory + "dallmannCSV").then((entry) => {

            const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download done!`,
              subTitle: `File was saved in: ${entry.toURL()}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });

            alertSuccess.present();

          }, (error) => {

            const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: `Download failed!`,
              subTitle: `Problem. Error: ${error.code}`,
              buttons: ['Ok']
            });

            alertFailure.present();

          });
      } else {
        console.log("browser");

        var blob = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = moment().format('LLL') + ".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        this.showToast("File was saved successfully");
      }



    });
```

The Problem: FileTransfer plugin needs for its first argument a path, where the generated file is located. But I have no idea where it is on my Android-device.

Do have any suggestions or a alternative way to do so? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use a Cordova plugin called File opener. That way the user can choose where to download the file and don't have to worry about paths. But I am unsure if it works on PC/Mac.